# React className loop adding comma

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code that I am using to add 'favorite' class to my objects when they are included in an array

```
        <p className={`${favorites.map(fav => fav._id === product._id ? 'favorite' : '')}`} onClick={() => addToFavs(product)} ><FaHeart/></p>
```

Which works somewhat, but only when the user has one favorite. When I try add another favorite it add the class name but also adds a comma either before or after the class name depending on the order it is in the array.

```
<p class="favorite,"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0">
```

or

```
<p class=",favorite"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0">
```

is there a better way to add a conditional class to each of the favorites or how can I remove the comma it is adding?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you just need to check if the `favorites` array includes the current product ID.

```
<p
  className={
    favorites.some(
      fav => fav._id === product._id
    ) ? 'favorite' : ''
  }
  onClick={() => addToFavs(product)} >
```

It'd be a bit easier if you had an array of the favorite IDs first, then you'd do

```
<p className={favoriteIds.includes(product._id) ? 'favorite' : ''}
```

Comment: Thank you for that second part I can convert them to id's and try that way if the first way doesn't work!

Comment: Worked like a charm!